# How to make all in one file with webpack

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I need to create all in one file.
The webpage im writing will be served from place where i do not have access to relative (and absolute) path.
So I need to put js in index.html file between  tag.

I have started from vue webpack template, modified it to so i have only two files - js and html file.
I can automate it using sed etc, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use webpack plugin [web-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/gwuhaolin/web-webpack-plugin) , [script-ext-html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/numical/script-ext-html-webpack-plugin) or [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin)

**The html-webpack-plugin and  extract-text-webpack-plugin way**

**webpack config:**

sample https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/examples/inline/webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('../..');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var webpackMajorVersion = require('webpack/package.json').version.split('.')[0];

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: './example.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/webpack-' + webpackMajorVersion),
    publicPath: '',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-
        loader', 'css-loader') }
    ]
  },
 plugins: [
 new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    inject: false,
    cache: false,
    filename: 'index.html',
    favicon: 'favicon.ico',
    title: 'demo'
  }),
  new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css')
]
};
```

**The web-webpack-plugin way**

**webpack config:**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    A: './a',
    B: './b',
  },
  plugins: [
    new WebPlugin({
        // file name or full path for output file, required.
        // pay attention not to duplication of name,as is will cover 
           other file
        filename: 'index.html',
        // this html's requires entry,must be an array.dependent resource will inject into html use the order entry in array.
        requires: {
            'inline': {
                _inline: true,
                _dist: true
            }
        }
    }),
  ]
};
```